# 3D bounded voronoi/delaunay

Tags: voronoi, delaunay

I'm searching for an open-source code computing the 3D voronoi/delaunay of a point cloud **bounded by a generic volume**.

I'm currently coding mostly on python using scipy to generate the diagrams, but 3D bounding is not supported. Mathworks community has a pair of codes such as [this](https://it.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/74742-3d_voronoi_cuboid_bounded?s_tid=srchtitle) with a bounded cuboid and [this](https://it.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/50772-polytope-bounded-voronoi-diagram-in-2d-and-3d?s_tid=srchtitle) with a convex polytope, but I would prefer faster languages since point clouds I'm working with are quite large.

Thanks,
ic